# Resolution of system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have to solve a system of differential equations but I don't get it. In the homogeneous part I think I don't get the right solution.

$ Y'(x) = A·Y(x)+ \vec v(x)$

With:

$ \vec v(x) = e^{2x}·
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$

$$
A = \left(
    \begin{matrix}
    2 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 2 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 3 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right)
$$

---

I've found the eigenvectors and eigenvalues:

$ \lambda_1 = 3   \rightarrow \vec v_1 = (1,0,1)$

$ \lambda_2 = 2 (double)   \rightarrow \vec v_2 = (1,0,0)$

I've to get other solution for $ \lambda_2 $ so that I do:

$ (A-\lambda_2·I)\vec u = \vec v_2 $

And I get: $ \vec u = (0,0,1) $

So that the final solution should be:

$ Y(x) = C_1·e^{3x}·
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$
+
$ C_2·e^{2x}·
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$
+
$ C_3·e^{2x}·\left(x·
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
\right
)
$

I tried to prove this is the right solution of the homogeneous part but I didn't get the same terms.

While $ Y'(x) $ has the following expression:

$ Y'(x) = C_1·e^{3x}·
\begin{bmatrix}
3 \\
0 \\
3
\end{bmatrix}
$
+
$ C_2·e^{2x}·
\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$
+
$ C_3·e^{2x}·\left(x·
\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
2
\end{bmatrix}
\right
)
$

The $ A·Y(x) $ is:

$ A·Y(x) = C_1·e^{3x}·
\begin{bmatrix}
3 \\
0 \\
3
\end{bmatrix}
$
+
$ C_2·e^{2x}·
\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$
+
$ C_3·e^{2x}·\left(x·
\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
3
\end{bmatrix}
\right
)
$

I don't know where is the error.
Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the vector u is wrong. The solution for second equation of second eigenvalue is (0,-1,1).

Comment: @choijh yes you're correct $u=(k,-1,1)$ for $\lambda=2$

Comment: @choijh, you're right. Thanks a lot!